# Buttons inside bootstrap well don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/8rhscamn/

```
<div class="well">                                            
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>                                           
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="butt1" onclick="alert('Hola')">Button <br />One</button>
    </div>                                                
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="butt2" onclick="alert('Hello')">Button <br />Two</button>
    </div>         
    <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>                                           
  </div>                                            
  </div>
```

It is a simple bootstrap well with columns inside that contains buttons that should execute a simple alert command. Problem is, when resized to the xs size column (like in the fiddle I am including), the buttons don't work. The buttons don't even are recognized as such (this is, the mouse indicator does not switch to the hand indicator when the pointer is over the button).

Any clue what I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: add button - position: relative; z-index: 1; - https://jsfiddle.net/9btht846/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `col-xs-12` classes. By default, the `col-sm-*` classes become full-width on small screen widths anyway. The floats in `col-xs-*` were causing the issue.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rhscamn/2/)</kbd>

---

If you were using the `col-sm-1` elements as horizontal padding, I suggest you use the `col-sm-offset-*` classes, eg

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
        <button>...</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <button>...</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rhscamn/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Your last div

```
<div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Do you need it? If you delete this div you can click on button, because this div cover your button so you can't click on it.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- Their are 2 ways. either make a function or can go through the second way -->   
function f(thetext)
{
    alert(thetext);
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="butt1" onclick="f('text1')">Button <br />One</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="butt2" onclick="f('text2')">Button <br />Two</button>

<!--Or you can go the following way by deleting the following line in your code.-->

<div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
```